# Google Drive Api V3 File Copy Not Working - PHP

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I'm trying to copy file from one drive to another. It works, if i use their official API console in the documentation but it fails with the following code.

```
<?php

require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google/Client.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google/Service.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client/vendor/autoload.php';


$clientId = 'myClientId';
$clientSecret = 'mySecret';
$redirectUri = 'redirectUri';
$client = new Google_Client();

$client->setClientId($clientId);
$client->setClientSecret($clientSecret);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirectUri);
$client->setAccessType('offline');
        
$refreshToken = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . "/token.txt");
$client->refreshToken($refreshToken);

$tokens = $client->getAccessToken();
$client->setAccessToken($tokens);

$client->setDefer(true);
$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

$fileId = "DemoFileID"; // Google File ID


$file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
$request = $service->files->copy($fileId, $file);
print_r($request);
```

I get the following error:

```
GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request Object ( [method:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request:private] => POST
 [requestTarget:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request:private] => [uri:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request:private] => GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri Object ( [scheme:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri:private] => https [userInfo:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri:private] => [host:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri:private] => www.googleapis.com 
[port:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri:private] => [path:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri:private] => /drive/v3/files/DemoFileID/copy [query:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri:private] => [fragment:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri:private] => ) 
[headers:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request:private] => Array ( [Host] => Array ( [0] => www.googleapis.com ) [content-type] => Array ( [0] => application/json ) [X-Php-Expected-Class] => Array ( [0] => Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile ) ) 
[headerNames:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request:private] => Array ( [content-type] => content-type [host] => Host [x-php-expected-class] => X-Php-Expected-Class ) [protocol:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request:private] => 1.1 [stream:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request:private] => )
```

Comment: It doesn't say error anywhere. It is just printing out the request object

Comment: But the file is not getting copied. I have checked the drive, i don't see the file.

Comment: Try wrapping it in try catch block so you can see if there is an error. Here is how https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/copy#php

Comment: I did that very first. but it is not printing error. it does not reach to error. it returns same above messages from the function as well and no files copied in the drive.

Comment: since you do not get any errors, are you sure $request = $service->files->copy($fileId, $file); does what you think it does?

Comment: If successful, this method returns a Files resource in the response body. So you need to figure out how to get it from response body but there is no error as i see it.

Comment: Hmm that i know but not getting what it should give.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works after commenting the line

$client->setDefer(true);

if anyone encounter same message like above. just change

$client->setDefer(true);

to

//$client->setDefer(true);